# Long Press event detection for entire app

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

Added a overlay with type System Overlay. I want to receive onLongPress event, and let all other events pass to the activity below. System Overlay is added but I am not able to receive any events.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Guys if you down vote no problem, at least point to a solution if the question is beneath you to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use root view:

`getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).setOnLongClickListner(<this or your own listener>)`

Implement this inside each onCreate method in each Activity you want.

Comment: Actually I want a unified solution. Like a view inserted using a base activity and then a GestureDetector set on that view.